# Strapi not updating API

Tags: heroku, strapi

everyone.

I have an [API](https://john-strapi.herokuapp.com/bands) on Strapi served by Heroku.

This is the [frontend](https://punkcore.com.br).

Thing is: logged in on Strapi admin served by Heroku (not locally), I can create/add more bands, but the API does not get updated. What can I possibly do?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Did you `Publish` the entries after creating them? `Strapi` will not reflect the newly created entries unless you `publish` them.

Comment: Yes, I did. They are all published in Strapi, but the API does not reflect the new bands. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Hi @JovaneRocha is it working for you? did you find what seems to be the problem? I had similar problem

Comment: Hi @NileshK. Unfortunately, it didn't work... I couldn't find the problem yet.

Comment: @JovaneRocha I got it working. I had wrong env on my strapi server. Also when you create new content type or fields make sure you are in development mode.

Comment: Thank you, @NileshK. I'll give it a try as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this usually happens if the env is messed up. Please check what is the endpoint it is pointing to.

Also whatever configurations or new fields you are adding always use development mode on strapi.

publish your content